# Websphere hates multi-release jars

Tags: java, websphere

This problem is duplicate to similar problems in Jetty, but I could not find literature about Websphere

- https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/1797
- [Error scanning entry "module-info.class" when starting Jetty server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45311295/error-scanning-entry-module-info-class-when-starting-jetty-server)

I have a Websphere 8.5.5.7 running over Java 7. Only today we discovered that upgrading log4j from 2.7 to 2.10 breaks the startup. Following is one of the many stack traces:

```
[01/03/18 10.12.14:154 CET] 000003d9 ecs           W com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl scanJAR unable to open input stream for resource module-info.class in archive WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar
                                 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.impl.ClassScanner.scanInputStream(ClassScanner.java:147)
    at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.impl.ClassScanner.scanInputStream(ClassScanner.java:124)
    at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.impl.ClassScanner.scanInputStream(ClassScanner.java:120)
    at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl.scanJAR(ScannerContextImpl.java:275)
    at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl.scanJARs(ScannerContextImpl.java:315)
    at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.WARScannerContext.scanInternal(WARScannerContext.java:76)
    at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl.scan(ScannerContextImpl.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl.getScannedClasses(ScannerContextImpl.java:70)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.scanForHandlesTypesClasses(WebAppImpl.java:760)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebAppImpl.java:601)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:406)
```

Basically the log4j developers had the great (but unlucky) idea of using multi-release jars for Java 9 to accommodate older Java runtimes.

Our installation **cannot be upgraded**. Those are the versions and we must keep them. I have tried to google around for multirelease jars with websphere but there seems to be no literature.

I would like to ask **if there is any configuration workaround** to disable massive scanning of jars at least in selected packages in the targeted version of websphere.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **I have found there is no real issue in the question**: I have determined that the exception is a warning and not a real startup error. The application is not prevented to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an existing APAR for this.  See APAR [PI89708](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI89708).

If that does not fix the problem, you should open a PMR so that IBM can fix it.

WebSphere Application Server traditional does provide a mechanism to reduce the amount of scanning of JAR files.  However, that might (or might not) be a workaround for this problem, since not all components of WAS respect the annotation scanning filters.  Though it is still worth looking at since reducing the scanning activity can improve deployment time.

Take a look at the amm.filter.properties file under *WAS_HOME*/properties.
Add names of JAR files that you do not want scanned to the "Ignore-Scanning-Archives" property.  There are more options for specifying JARs to be filtered from scanning.  You can find more information [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/trun_app_reduce_annot.html).

Also note that WAS 8.5.5 was released before multi-release JARs existed.  So the support, or more accurately tolerance, has to be added in service. I say tolerance, because Java 9 is not supported at this time. For now, WAS simply has to tolerate the existence of classes under the META-INF directory.

If you absolutely cannot upgrade or patch the application server, then the simplest option is to modify the log4J JAR file, removing the classes under the META-INF directory.  I know that is not desirable either, since you shouldn't have to modify a third-party JAR, but I have doubts that the filter will work in this case.  So, without patching the application server, it might be the only option.

As you pointed out in your comment, in this particular case, since LOG4J does not have JAVA EE annotations, the warning message can be ignored. The application should start and function normally. If however, the JAR contained Java EE annotations, then those annotations would not have been processed.  If that were the case, I would expect the application to start, but it might not function correctly.

> > > >
> > >       Additional APARs were added since the original answer to this question.  Here is the complete list of APARs:
> > >       [PI89708](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI89708), [PI93744](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI93744), [PI96826](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI96826), [PH02014](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PH02014), [PH03710](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PH03710).

Comment: We were considering applying `Ignore-Scanning-Archives` at WAR level. The very problem is that we cannot request the customer to patch or upgrade Websphere, because they will simply refuse and demand us to downgrade our software.

Comment: Added option of modifying LOG4J JAR.  Classes under META-INF are not needed as WebSphere Application Server has no support for classes in that directory tree, nor does it have support for Java V9 .class files.

Comment: Added that the warning message can be ignored in this case.

Comment: Until the PI89708 is fixed you may use a very simple workaround that seems to work for me (I couldn't ignore that exception because WAS was trying to replace the ear every minute over and over again - on node sync event).
There's that mentioned `Ignore-Scanning-Archives` MANIFEST.MF entry that can be used to list (comma separated) jars to exclude from annotation scanning. However that requires you to explicitly list the full jar names to exclude.
Instead, use `Ignore-Scanning-Packages` and in the following way: `Ignore-Scanning-Packages: META-INF.versions`
That should do the trick.

Comment: And if you can't modify the ear, use JVM system property `com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.context.filter.packages` to do the same.
See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/trun_app_reduce_annot.html for more details.