# Springboot GCP app engine deployment failure

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, embedded-jetty

I have been trying to deploy my spring boot project to GCP app engine. I believe that GCP app engines by default uses "jetty" server and I have configured to work with embedded jetty as well. But while deploying my app using `mvn gcloud:deploy`(plugin used gcloud-maven-plugin) I am unable to deploy to GCP.

I always end up with the following error

```
Beginning interaction for module default...
0% Scanning for jsp files.
2018-10-04 12:50:39.631:INFO::main: Logging initialized @389ms
2018-10-04 12:50:43.937:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.q.QuickStartWebApp@4f80542f{/,[file:/Users/a1345875/Documents/bitbucket-code/target/appengine-staging/, jar:file:/Users/a1345875/Documents/bitbucket-code/target/appengine-staging/WEB-INF/lib/springfox-swagger-ui-2.7.0.jar!/META-INF/resources],STARTING}
MultiException[java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/ProcessIdUtil.class from jar file:/Users/a1345875/Documents/bitbucket-code/target/appengine-staging/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/StackLocator.class from jar file:/Users/a1345875/Documents/bitbucket-code/target/appengine-staging/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry module-info.class from jar file:/Users/a1345875/Documents/bitbucket-code/target/appengine-staging/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry module-info.class from jar file:/Users/a1345875/Documents/bitbucket-code/target/appengine-staging/WEB-INF/lib/asm-commons-6.0.jar, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry module-info.class from jar file:/Users/a1345875/Documents/bitbucket-code/target/appengine-staging/WEB-INF/lib/asm-6.0.jar, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry module-info.class from jar file:/Users/a1345875/Documents/bitbucket-code/target/appengine-staging/WEB-INF/lib/asm-tree-6.0.jar]
   at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.scanForAnnotations(AnnotationConfiguration.java:536)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:447)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:479)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1337)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.quickstart.QuickStartWebApp.doStart(QuickStartWebApp.java:165)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
   at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.QuickStartGenerator.generate(QuickStartGenerator.java:68)
   at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.QuickStartGenerator.main(QuickStartGenerator.java:47)
Failed to generate /Users/a1345875/Documents/bitbucket-code/target/appengine-staging/WEB-INF/quickstart-web.xml
```

This is my app.yaml configuration by the way

```
runtime: java
env: flex
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  script: this field is required, but ignored

resources:
  memory_gb: 2.0
```

And this is a link to my pom.xml
https://github.com/vijayakumar-psg587/POMfile

Could you guys please help. I posted the same question in googlecommunity github page but no response yet as of now. I am unsure if I am making any mistake with the configuration.

This is the link to the github community page
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/community/issues/557

EDIT: Currently I removed the use of jetty server from my pom and used tomcat instead. I also made use of appengine-maven-plugin as suggested in the google docs

This time I was able to deploy and after deploying I was trying to access my swagger and this is what I got back analysing the logs:

.  Without it, getSession() is allowed, but manipulation of sessionattributes is not.]

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Session support is not enabled in appengine-web.xml.  To enable sessions, put <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled> in that file.  Without it, getSession() is allowed, but manipulation of sessionattributes is not.
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.StubSessionManager$StubSession.throwException(StubSessionManager.java:86) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.StubSessionManager$StubSession.setAttribute(StubSessionManager.java:71) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache.saveRequest(HttpSessionRequestCache.java:59) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.sendStartAuthentication(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleSpringSecurityException(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:185) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:141) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:206) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:130) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:105) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:155) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:123) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.ParseBlobUploadHandler.handle(ParseBlobUploadHandler.java:120) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1182) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppEngineWebAppContext.doHandle(AppEngineWebAppContext.java:171) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:297) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:539) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:333) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnection.handle(RpcConnection.java:202) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnector.serviceRequest(RpcConnector.java:81) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:123) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:692) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:654) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:624) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:818) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:274) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_112-google-v7]
```

I also ended up with some exceptions while deploying to app engine but it was finally a success. I am unsure if it has to do anything with my error while accessing the app from app engine

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: Beginning interaction for module default...
[INFO] GCLOUD: 0% Scanning for jsp files.
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2018-10-09 18:29:23.305:INFO::main: Logging initialized @145ms
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2018-10-09 18:29:23.451:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.3.18.v20170406
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2018-10-09 18:29:24.906:WARN:oeja.ClassInheritanceHandler:qtp1066516207-17: 
[INFO] GCLOUD: java.lang.NullPointerException
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:936)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ClassInheritanceHandler.addToInheritanceMap(ClassInheritanceHandler.java:72)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ClassInheritanceHandler.handle(ClassInheritanceHandler.java:58)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser$MyClassVisitor.visit(AnnotationParser.java:476)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:650)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:525)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:978)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:958)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:902)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:851)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:163)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:546)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2018-10-09 18:29:26.910:INFO:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: Scanning elapsed time=3051ms
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2018-10-09 18:29:26.926:INFO:oejq.QuickStartDescriptorGenerator:main: Quickstart generating
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2018-10-09 18:29:26.942:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.q.QuickStartWebApp@7c16905e{/,[file:XXXX/target/appengine-staging/, jar:file:///XXXXX/target/appengine-staging/WEB-INF/lib/springfox-swagger-ui-2.7.0.jar!/META-INF/resources],AVAILABLE}
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2018-10-09 18:29:26.945:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @3787ms
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2018-10-09 18:29:26.950:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Stopped o.e.j.q.QuickStartWebApp@7c16905e{/,file:XXXXX/target/appengine-staging/,UNAVAILABLE}
[INFO] GCLOUD: 0% Generated git repository information file.
[INFO] GCLOUD: Success.
[INFO] GCLOUD: Temporary staging for module default directory left in /XXXX/target/appengine-staging
Oct 09, 2018 6:29:27 PM com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.CloudSdk logCommand
INFO: submitting command: /Applications/gcloud-sdk/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud app deploy XXXXX/target/AdTechServices-0.0.1/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
[INFO] GCLOUD: Services to deploy:
[INFO] GCLOUD: 
[INFO] GCLOUD: descriptor:      [XXXXX/target/AdTechServices-0.0.1/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml]
[INFO] GCLOUD: source:          [XXXXXX/target/AdTechServices-0.0.1]
[INFO] GCLOUD: target project:  [XXXXXX]
[INFO] GCLOUD: target service:  [default]
[INFO] GCLOUD: target version:  [20181009t182937]
[INFO] GCLOUD: target url:      [https://XXXXX.appspot.com]
[INFO] GCLOUD: 
[INFO] GCLOUD: 
[INFO] GCLOUD: Beginning deployment of service [default]...
[INFO] GCLOUD: #============================================================#
[INFO] GCLOUD: #= Uploading 18 files to Google Cloud Storage               =#
[INFO] GCLOUD: #============================================================#
[INFO] GCLOUD: File upload done.
[INFO] GCLOUD: Updating service [default]...
[INFO] GCLOUD: ............................done.
[INFO] GCLOUD: Setting traffic split for service [default]...
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45311295/error-scanning-entry-module-info-class-when-starting-jetty-server

Comment: HI @JoakimErdfelt. I went through the stackoverflow question already. This is a similar error that occurs even after upgrading to jdk 10 (since JDK9 is no longer supported by oracle)

Answer (score 1):

As seen by your output

- MultiException[

  - java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/ProcessIdUtil.class from jar file:/Users/a1345875/Documents/bitbucket-code/target/appengine-staging/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar,
  - java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/StackLocator.class from jar file:/Users/a1345875/Documents/bitbucket-code/target/appengine-staging/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar,
  - java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry module-info.class from jar file:/Users/a1345875/Documents/bitbucket-code/target/appengine-staging/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar,
  - java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry module-info.class from jar file:/Users/a1345875/Documents/bitbucket-code/target/appengine-staging/WEB-INF/lib/asm-commons-6.0.jar,
  - java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry module-info.class from jar file:/Users/a1345875/Documents/bitbucket-code/target/appengine-staging/WEB-INF/lib/asm-6.0.jar,
  - java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry module-info.class from jar file:/Users/a1345875/Documents/bitbucket-code/target/appengine-staging/WEB-INF/lib/asm-tree-6.0.jar]

Along with your output stating `jetty-9.3.18.v20170406`.

The key details are:

- `META-INF/versions/9/`
- `module-info.class`

This has been previously pointed out in an older question at [Error scanning entry "module-info.class" when starting Jetty server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45311295/error-scanning-entry-module-info-class-when-starting-jetty-server)

You have 3 JEP-238 Jar files present in your webapp.

- WEB-INF/lib/asm-tree-6.0.jar
- WEB-INF/lib/asm-6.0.jar
- WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar

You *MUST* use Jetty 9.4.9 (or newer) to support any Java runtime where JEP-238 Jar files are present.

Also note that asm-6.0 is for Java 8 bytecode and will not work with Java 9 or newer bytecode.
You'll need a newer asm jar if you have newer bytecode, *or* are using JEP-238 Jar files on newer Java runtimes (such as Java 9 or Java 10 or Java 11)

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I did try with your suggestion but ended up with another issue (i totally forgot what was that).I kept getting issues with App Engine flex deployment and ended up changing the deployment to standard. Modified the app.yaml file to appengine-web.xml and deployed as war and that worked for me. I will try again to deploy it to flex environment and see if I can get it done. Thanks though :)